# fstat is failing with invalid argument

Tags: c, linux

```
fileDes= open(dbPathname, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH);
}
printf("File %s opened successfully with handle %d\n", dbPathname, fileDes );
if(-1 == fileDes)
{
    PERS_ERROR( "pers_db_open_default: File %s opened Failed %d \n", dbPathname, fileDes );
    return NULL; //return PERS_COM_FAILURE;
}

*db = fileDes;
printf("file info:  FD=[%d], &FD=[%d], fileDes=[%d]  \n", (*db),(db), fileDes );

if( 0 != fstat(fileDes, &sb))
{;
    perror("fileInfo() fstat-perror=   \n");
    printf("\nfstat error: [%s] and st.st_mode is [%d]\n",strerror(errno), sb.st_mode);

    return NULL; 
}
```

**output:-**

```
fileInfo() fstat-perror=
: Invalid argument
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Can you please post the complete code ? As we don't know what's the type of `db` and `sb`.

Comment: What is that `}` doing on the line after the `fileDes` assignment?

Comment: int *db = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
struct stat sb;

Comment: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Where is the rest of the output? What do the `File ... opened` and `file info` lines say?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that shows everything you're doing. It's impossible to tell what's wrong from this snippet.

Comment: Why there is a semicolon after } `if( 0 != fstat(fileDes, &sb))
{;`

Comment: @GouravT Here `int db = (int)malloc(sizeof(int));` `db` should be of pointer type, isn't it ?

Comment: @GouravT `int db = (int)malloc(sizeof(int));`: allocating memory for a single `int` is pointless, there are probably other things wrong elsewhere in your code. Please read this: [ask] and [edit] your question and show a [mcve]. All relevant information must be _in the question_.

Comment: File /mnt/data/Persistence/mnt-wt/App/wt.db opened successfully with handle 7
pers_db_open_default  FD=[7], &FD=[922543632], fileDes=[7]  
fileInfo() fstat-perror=   
: Invalid argument

Comment: Assuming `db` is a pointer to `int`, `printf("file info:  FD=[%d], &FD=[%d], fileDes=[%d]  \n", (*db),(db), fileDes );` invokes undefined behavior by using the improper format specifier `%d` to print its value.

Comment: You are on 64bit?